# How can I configure my UnitOfWork/Repository to work when an `await`ed call changes threads?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nhibernate, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

How can I configure my UnitOfWork/Repository to work when an `await`ed call changes threads?

The code here is a fictional scenario which represents a common pattern we have in our production code.

When `await Task.Delay()` (which represents a call to an external service) is called, the remainder of the code in the `RequestHandler` executes on a different thread. I understand this is by-design behavior of using `await`. This throws an exception when the audit entry is added to the repository because the unit of work was opened on the previous thread.

In my opinion, everything in the request handler should be in the same "unit of work"/transaction. But I also think it's reasonable to assume that I should be able to await a call like I'm doing here. What is the right approach then?

From my reading on the subject, most answers seem to say a unit of work should be short-lived so that it only operates on one thread, which makes sense.

I thought about just using `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of using `await`, but this doesn't seem to be the correct solution. I understand there is a risk of deadlocks with this approach, but it's also a bit confusing as using `await` compiles just fine.

I have a functioning project in [my GitHub account](https://github.com/James654987/MultiThreadedUnitOfWork) which shows our architecture and has tests showing the problem I'm facing.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediatR;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.Models;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkAndRepositories;

namespace MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.RequestsAndHandlers.Multi_Threaded
{
    public class GetUserNameByIdRequestHandlerMultiThreaded : IRequestHandler<GetUserNameByIdRequestMultiThreaded, GetUserNameByIdResponseMultiThreaded>
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public GetUserNameByIdRequestHandlerMultiThreaded(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<GetUserNameByIdResponseMultiThreaded> Handle(GetUserNameByIdRequestMultiThreaded request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = _repository.Get<User>(request.Id);

            // This is to simulate a call to an external service
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);

            // The code after this point executes in a different thread
            var auditEntry = new Audit(nameof(User));

            // This line fails because the unit of work was opened on the previous thread
            _repository.Add(auditEntry);

            return new GetUserNameByIdResponseMultiThreaded(user.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the test scenario that calls the request handler above.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediatR;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.IoC;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.Models;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.RequestsAndHandlers.Multi_Threaded;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.RequestsAndHandlers.Single_Threaded;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkAndRepositories;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetUp()
        {
            _mediator = Container.Resolve<IMediator>();
            _repository = Container.Resolve<IRepository>();

            using (var uow = UnitOfWork.Start())
            {
                var user = new User("Test User");

                _repository.Add(user);

                uow.Complete();
            }
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            if (UnitOfWork.Current != null)
            {
                UnitOfWork.Current.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private IMediator _mediator;
        private IRepository _repository;

        [Test]
        public async Task MultiThreadedTest()
        {
            var request = new GetUserNameByIdRequestMultiThreaded(1);

            GetUserNameByIdResponseMultiThreaded response;

            try
            {
                using (var uow = UnitOfWork.Start())
                {
                    response = await _mediator.Send(request);

                    uow.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            Assert.That(response, Is.Not.Null);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Turns out the problem is with this request state class. I don't really understand why this was created or why it's marked with `ThreadStatic` but it's causing the problems I'm experiencing. Unfortunately it's apparently needed for some parts of our website as the site breaks if I remove it. Thanks for the help everyone.

`RequestState` class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.RequestStates
{
    public class PerThreadRequestState : IRequestState
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static IDictionary<string, object> _state;
        
        private static IDictionary<string, object> State => _state ?? (_state = new Dictionary<string, object>());

        public void Store<T>(T something)
        {
            lock (State)
            {
                State[typeof(T).FullName] = something;
            }
        }
        
        public T Get<T>()
        {
            lock (State)
            {
                if (State.TryGetValue(typeof(T).FullName, out var state)) 
                    return (T)state;

                return default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`UnitOfWork`

```
using System.Transactions;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.IoC;
using MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.RequestStates;
using NHibernate;
using IsolationLevel = System.Data.IsolationLevel;

namespace MultiThreadedUnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkAndRepositories
{
    public sealed class UnitOfWorkWithNHibernateTransaction : IUnitOfWork
    {
        internal UnitOfWorkWithNHibernateTransaction()
        {
            if (Current != null)
                throw new UnitOfWorkException("Unit of work should not be nested");

            var sessionFactory = Container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
            Session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

            if (Transaction.Current == null)
                Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

            Current = this;
        }

        private static IUnitOfWork Current
        {
            get => Container.Resolve<IRequestState>().Get<IUnitOfWork>();
            set => Container.Resolve<IRequestState>().Store(value);
        }

        public ISession Session { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your DbContext scoped?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The most common UoW/Repo implementation (EF core) does not require single-threaded access. It is written to allow one-thread-at-a-time access. I recommend making your UoW/Repo implementation also allow one-thread-at-a-time access, and then `await` will work naturally.

Comment: @GHDevOps I'm not sure. The Session (NHibernate equivalent to DbContext) is not managed by the IoC container and is just started by calling sessionFactory.OpenSession()

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it's a custom error message. The Unit of Work class holds a reference to the session/dbcontext and it gets checked for null. When the new thread is started after the await call, the reference to the session is now null and our exception is thrown.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the reply. Your blogs have helped me understand async behavior better, but I still have a ways to go. Do you have any recommendations or resources on how to implement one-thread-at-a-time access?

Comment: It sounds like the same-thread restriction is artificial and is imposed by yourself. You could consider including in the question an explanation for this design decision.

Comment: One-thread-at-a-time is the *default* behavior in .NET. I recommend speaking with the person who wrote the UoW code as to why they chose something more restrictive.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately this was written 10 years ago by a dev who's no longer here, so I'm attempting to make sense of it all.

Comment: Turns out there is a dictionary used to store the current of unit of work, which is marked with `ThreadStatic` and is causing the issue I'm experiencing. I am not sure why, but will continue looking into it.